# Scroll to top of page after closing div block

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code which shows and hides a div block which contains a lot of (initially hidden) text, what I want it to do is to scroll up to a specific id="up" point when the div block gets closed.

Code I am using to toggle the div block:

```js
function openCity(e){
    var t, n=document.getElementsByClassName("city");
    for(t=0;t<n.length;t++) {
       n[t].style.display="none";
    }
    document.getElementById(e).style.display="block"
}
```

This is what I am using as the point to scroll up to `<div class="floatfullwidth" id="up"></div>`

This is the block that holds the text     `<div class="w3-container city" style="display:none">Lots of text</div>`

This is the button used to close the div block `<button class="nav-toggle" onclick="openCity('Locale')"><< Go Back / Close</button>`

Any help seriously appreciated.

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to scroll to related div's position:

```
<div class="floatfullwidth" id="up"></div>
```

in your js:

```
function openCity(e) {
    var t, n = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
    for (t = 0; t < n.length; t++)n[t].style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(e).style.display = "block";
    const div = document.getElementById('up');
    window.scrollTo(0, div.offsetTop);
}
```